# dynamic route not updated

Tags: 8, routes

I have dynamic route: from [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122201) example

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\example\Routing\ExampleRoutes.
 */

namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Defines dynamic routes.
 */
class ExampleRoutes {

public function routes() {
  $route_collection = new RouteCollection();

  $route = new Route(
    // Path to attach this route to:
    '/example',
    // Route defaults:
    array(
      '_controller' => '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content',
    '_title' => 'Hello'
  ),
  // Route requirements:
  array(
    '_permission'  => 'access content',
  )
);
// Add the route under the name 'example.content'.
$route_collection->add('example.content', $route);
return $route_collection;
}

}
```

the problem here is: the route is not automatically updated (or accessible)
until i clear cache, then it works.

question is: how to make the new created route immediately works?
*i try to avoid clear cache command (which i don't think this is the right solution)

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the necessary entry in the routing.yml file?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks, do you mind to advise me the 'necessary entry' in routing.yml? i do `route_callbacks:` with service and made the correspondent services, pointing to the `ExampleRoutes::routes` that i show above in my questions - do i missed anything else?

Comment: That is the _necessary entry_ I was referring to. I should check what the module for image styles does, and see if there is something that module does that your code doesn't.

Comment: Why do you need to add new routes dynamically?

Comment: @Eyal If the OP is showing the code effectively used, that is not even a dynamic route. If that is the effective code they are using, I would not use it.

Comment: @AnD if you are not trying to dynamically create routes then there is no problem with rebuilding the cached after you change the routes (that is what I usually do).

Comment: I make (include delete)  entity which will generate (or remove) route to that entity, i can do that manual rebuild cache, but just wondering if this the right/best solution...

Comment: Yes, it is fine to rebuild the caches after you create a new entity type.

Comment: I see, if that the case then i guess rebuild cache is the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the routes you have to call [RouteBuilder::rebuild](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteBuilder.php/function/RouteBuilder%3A%3Arebuild/8.3.x):

```
\Drupal::service('router.builder')->rebuild();
```

This is not what you want to run very often during normal operation of the site. This can take several seconds. It's also not possible to run more than one update process simultaneously. So routes are in general static, even the dynamic ones.